# Connection prematurely closed DURING response ( generate by Spring cloud Gateway )

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netty

Its a Microservice architecture and high RPS (Requests-per-second) application using spring cloud.

**spring-boot: 2.5.0**

**spring cloud: 2020.0.5**

spring cloud-gateway received traffic from a **Nginx SLB**, and with the help of eureka-server flowed traffic in the downstream microservice services.

on average 80% request served happly, but other 20% request throw this error randomly.
and finally Nginx logg this request with 500.

```
    2024-01-14 16:49:41.840 ERROR [openapi-edge-gateway,,] 10583 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [961a50ed-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/employee-service/get-employee-info"

    reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
    Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ springfox.boot.starter.autoconfigure.SwaggerUiWebFluxConfiguration$CustomWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/employee-service/get-employee-info" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
        
    Stack trace:
```